# What is the title of this song?

Tags: character-identification, songs

At the end of http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=zyDqrkZxco8

update: the song title is probably on the 4th line from the bottom in the credits, but I cannot read it

Comment: Is it an another song you are trying to spot?

Comment: no, I always wanted the last one, I just mistakenly believed that it is from one of those movies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title is 好像好像谈恋爱, the TV series or movie is 爱情公寓.

Update. The 4th line from the bottom is 问候歌 ("Song of Greetings").

One of the different versions on Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F_5F0DcpqP8

Comment: thanks, I found the same version https://youtu.be/mJ-JK0t7mrE